# undefined method `remember_token=' for #<User:0x0000010b454f50>

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

I'm working through Rails Tutorial and am stuck in Ch 8 -- the bit about login sessions. The error appears when I submit an email/pw combination that should create a new session.

Here's the error:

```
NoMethodError in SessionsController#create
undefined method `remember_token=' for #<User:0x0000010b454f50>

Extracted source (around line #435):
      else
        match = match_attribute_method?(method.to_s)
        match ? attribute_missing(match, *args, &block) : super
      end
    end
```

From there I look under create in the sessions controller. And I try to see where I call the remember_token method.

Sessions controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create

    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)

    if user &&  user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])

      log_in user
      #if 1 then remember, else forget
      params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(user) : forget(user)

      remember user

      redirect_to user
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination' 
      render 'new'
    end

  end

  def destroy
    #call log_out helper method
    log_out if logged_in?

    redirect_to root_url
  end


end
```

I call `remember` which looks important. Here's the session helper:

```
module SessionsHelper
  #Logs in the given user.
  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  def remember(user)
    #generate a new token and provide the encrypted hash
    user.remember

    cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id]=user.id
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token]=user.remember_token
  end

  def current_user
    #if session user id exists, then set to user_id and then...
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
      #set @current_user to the correct user account
      @current_user||= User.find_by(id: user_id)

    #else, if signed cookie user id exists, set to user_id and then...
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
      #set user to the correct user account and...
      user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
      #if user is authenticated, then log them in and set @current_user to user
      if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
        log_in user
        @current_user = user
      end
    end
  end

  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  #Forgets a persistent session
  def forget(user)
    user.forget
    cookies.delete(:user_id)
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end

  def log_out
    forget(current_user)
    session.delete(:user_id)
    @current_user = nil
  end

end
```

That looks like the key -- `cookies.permanent[:remember_token]=user.remember_token`.

But I don't know how to define the remember_token method. When I go through the tutorial I don't see any methods that describe remember_token. The closest I get is in the user model (method called `remember`):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
before_save { self.email = email.downcase }

belongs_to :courses
belongs_to :lessons

validates :first_name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
validates :last_name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }

validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }, 
     uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

has_secure_password
validates :password, length: { minimum: 6}

  #Returns the hash digest of the given string
  def User.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
      BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)

    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end

  #Returns a random token
  def User.new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  #creates a new token (random string) then encypts it by returning a hash
  def remember
    self.remember_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
  end

  #Returns true if the given token matches the digest
  def authenticated?(remember_token)
    return false if remember_digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(remember_digest).is_password?(remember_token)
  end

  #forgets a user
  def forget
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
  end
end
```

Am I understanding the interplay between the session controller, session helper and the user model? Is the interplay not setup right - and that's throwing the error? I don't understand why it doesn't work...

Background:
The tutorial intentionally avoids putting the remember_token in the database, as a security feature. So that isn't the problem.

Comment: i actually did not read your question but whatever... did you run rake db:migrate? those errors usually show that the database is missing a field

Comment: All migrations are up -- so that's not the problem.

Comment: does the db have the field?

Comment: No, the db doesn't have remember_token as a field. But it isn't meant to.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was in the sessions controller -- I didn't understand the ternary operator and had repeated a bit of its functionality. Here's the original Create method:

```
  def create

    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)

    if user &&  user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])

      log_in user
      #if 1 then remember, else forget
      params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(user) : forget(user)

      remember user

      redirect_to user
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination' 
      render 'new'
    end

  end
```

This bit `remember user` is redundant.

The ternary `params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(user) : forget(user)` means if `params[:session][:remember_me]` is 1, then `remember(user)` else `forget(user)`.

By then calling `remember user` (which is the same as `remember(user)`) I was executing the same things twice, causing the error.